# Deducing the type of a return value

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

As an example stripped down to the bare minimum, we have the container:

```
template<class T> class container{
public: 
  T t[3];
};
```

I would like to make operations on these containers that combine various values of `T`. For example by adding a container of real numbers to a container of complex ones. This is done by declaring the operators:

```
 inline container<std::complex<double>> operator+(const container<double>& A, const container<std::complex<double>>& B){
  container<std::complex<double>> sum;
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
    sum.t[i]=A.t[i]+B.t[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

inline container<std::complex<double>> operator+(const container<std::complex<double>>& A, const container<double>& B){
  return B+A; 
}
```

I cannot use `auto` since I am dealing with the container and not an element.

This works fine except that it leads to code duplication. In a real-life example, there are more operators and I can have containers of containers.

Is there a better way to do it?

I have tried to play with `std::conditional` and `std:::is_same` but this does not seem to work.

Many thanks!

Comment: what code duplication exatcly are you worried about?

Comment: You can use `auto` for the return type, if that's what you mean. Could you show an example of code duplication? If you're adding containers of different types, it seems you would need different implementations.

Comment: An example of how `auto` is not working for you would be helpful.  As is, there is nothing stoping you from using `auto` as the return type of either of those functions.

Comment: The code duplication stems from the fact that I have to write a function for each operator, for each combination of argument types, for each possible order of the arguments but also for containers containing containers. It does the job but it does not feel elegant.

Comment: I could use auto for the return type but not for the container holding the result.

Comment: Why not?  You can use `auto sum = B`; and then just add the elements of `A` to `sum` and then return `sum`.

Comment: Instead of describing the issue, why not show the code that you would like to write, but can't?

Comment: But I would not know if I have to start with A or B. If I start with the complex value, it's fine but not with the real one.

Comment: How would you not know?  You're writing the function, deciding what it does, why can't you decide which of the parameters you want to start with?

Comment: The code works. I just don't find it elegant. What I would like to do is deduce the return value from the types of the arguments. The only simple way I see would be with something like this:

Comment: you want to make it a template to have same implementation for different containers? different types of elements? In the code you posted there isnt really anything to be deduced, well you use `auto` as return, because the types are all right there

Comment: why don't you create template aliases?
ex.:
`template<typename T> using complex_container_t = container<std::complex<T>>;`?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like (untested):

```
template <class LhsElem, class RhsElem>
inline auto operator+(const container<LhsElem>& A, const container<RhsElem>& B){

  // Probe what the result type will be
  using ResultType = decltype(std::declval<LhsElem const&>() + std::declval<RhsElem const&>());

  container<ResultType > sum;
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
    sum.t[i]=A.t[i]+B.t[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I was trying to do which did not work for a silly reason. I am going to post it below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was trying to do. The problem I was facing is that I did not know I had to add `::value` at the end of that `std::is_same<...>` expression so it was not working and I had began to think it was impossible.

```
template<class T1, class T2> inline auto operator+(const container<T1>& A, 
                                                   const container<T2>& B){
  std::conditional<std::is_same<T1, std::complex<double>>::value 
                   || std::is_same<T2, std::complex<double>>::value,   
                   container<std::complex<double>>, container<double>> sum;
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
    sum.t[i]=A.t[i]+B.t[i];
  }
  return sum;  
}
```

Comment: I'm using gcc but other compilers could be less lax about this.

Comment: I will take a look.Thanks!